# Why doesn't my simple python script start tomcat work when launched as a cron job?

Tags: python, unix, cron

I have a simple python script that starts tomcat, like so:

```
  print "Attempting to start tomcat ..."
  subprocess.call('sudo service '+instance+' start',shell=True)
```

Works fine when I run it myself at the command line.

However, when I do a 'sudo crontab -e' and add it as a cron job like do ...

```
*/15 * * * * /home/myscript.py > /home/myscript-output.txt
```

The script runs (because the output file gets created) but tomcat doesn't start.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The output file will be created as soon as the shell processes the line. It doesn't mean the script executes correctly. Try redirecting standard error to the file also (`&>/home/myscript-output.txt` or `> /home/myscript-output.txt 2>&1`) and see what you get.

Comment: Might want to try subprocess.check_call() and subprocess.CalledProcessError() to see what output you get. Cron is run in its own context so its probably sudo or service aren't available without the full path.

Comment: Can you try setting the crontab to run that as root and drop the "sudo"? This is dangerous, but it might be the case that the reason it's not running is because of user privileges.

Comment: What user's crontab is this? Does that user have password-less `sudo` access to that command? Why are you starting a shell for that `sudo` command?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, when I did &> I see there are these errors in the output: "sudo: service: command not found"

Comment: @EtanReisner the "sudo" is there because otherwise starting tomcat fails with a "permission denied" error

Comment: It does that from your user. Does it do that from the crontab user (whoever that is)? Is this just supposed to make sure your service stays running in case it crashes/ec.?